# How do I filter the below array and get ["h","a"] output?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Const array = [1,2,3,4,"h","a","$","@"]
// Here array of numbers, strings, special characters
```

I wanted the output to be

```
["h","a"]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's special about `["h","a"]`? Are you just trying to get all the alphabetic characters?

Answer (score 2):

```
const alphabets = array.filter(item => {
    return typeof item === "string" && item.match(/[a-z]/i)
}
)
console.log(alphabets)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,"h","a","$","@"]
let n =array.filter((x) => typeof x === "string" && /^[a-zA- 
Z]+$/.test(x))
console.log(n)
```

I used Regex to compare and filtered to a new array this should do what you want

Comment: don't pass a parameter to `regex.test` without checking its type first.

Comment: Not needed to check type brother it will work fine without that

Comment: no, it won't - try `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(false)`, or `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(NaN)`

Comment: @Alnitak Why? [`test`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp.prototype.test) always coerces its argument to a string. `String(false)` is `"false"`; `String(NaN)` is `"NaN"`. What about this is “not working”? What else would you expect from that? The _boolean_ `false` can neither be included in a string nor in a regex. So how else could it ever be possible to make `test` work differently?

Comment: @SebastianSimon precisely, and some of those conversions (see my previous comment) can produce strings that _match_ the regex.

Comment: @SebastianSimon `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(false)` returns `true`, and would therefore end up incorrectly appearing in the output array (as does `NaN`)

Comment: @Alnitak `test` is not a method to check if a regular expression can be matched against a _boolean_. It only ever works for strings. The concept of matching a regular expression against anything other than a string does not make sense to begin with! So, of course, `false` and `NaN` are coerced to strings first, and `/[a-z]/.test(false)` is correctly `true`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon there are plenty of non-strings in the OP's test data!

Comment: As it happens, the code will work by accident for `false` and `NaN` because the `.filter` predicate is returning `x` instead of the boolean result of the `.test` call (thereby relying on yet another implicit type coercion!).   It _wouldn't_ work for `true`.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, there’s also no clear problem statement and no own attempt in the OP’s post. The OP may just as well be confused about what they’re actually looking for. If they don’t want other data types to be coerced to strings, they should specify that in the post.

Comment: Edited it thanks for correction

Comment: either way - the first rule to avoid almost every single JavaScript 'WAT?!' is to explicitly coerce variables to the expected type (or perform a type check) before using them.   Go look up the recent thread about `parseInt(0.0000005)`.

Comment: @Alnitak Or just be aware of how the API works. `parseInt` expects a string argument, not a number argument, for example.

Comment: Ok I'll edit it

Comment: @SebastianSimon I know that, you know that, but the author of this answer apparently didn't, which is _why I raised this point in the first place_!

Comment: @Alnitak Bruh